# Angular CLI: Inject css on Sass compile without full reload?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli, browser-sync

We have our Angular 4 app scaffolded with angular cli, using scss as the default styling. We run the app with

`ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss -o`

To get scss source maps. This works fine, app compiles, runs, source maps work, etc.

However, coming from the Angular1/Gulp/Browsersync world, I am missing the injection of the built css without a full page reload. Currently, whenever I edit a sass file, webpack compiles and reloads the page in Chrome.

Is this the only way to work now?  Is there no way to simply force a refresh of the css without a reload (like browsersync did it in the Gulp days)?

Comment: Yes this is very annoying indeed. Any updates on this? I am working with angular 7 and would be happy if there is a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the same as CSS injection, but will make your page reload & compile a hell of a lot faster!

With Angular 7 you can follow [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/configure-hmr.md) to enable HMR. (Hot Module Replacement)

It will also make reloading your .ts files very fast!

---

Small addendum:

I think you can infact load the CSS changed by injection but following this piece of the [HMR documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#hmr-with-stylesheets)